# Automatic Login with wrong password on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, passwords

This morning I was forced to change my password on my Windows 8 laptop. Since then my Active Directory gets locked within seconds after login.

To me this looks like there's some nasty software that stored my passwords and tries to login with the outdated password until I get locked.

According to the help desk this happens withing seconds after login. But they cannot tell me what kind of program or service it is.

Any ideas how to find the guilty software?

Comment: Enable the appropriate events for logging within AD so you can figure out where the account is being locked from. It might be as simple as having a mail client that's using the old password.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Disable wifi/remove the wire and log on. Then check startup programs.

Comment: Depending on your role you won't be able to do that. It has to be done by your IT department. For example see [How to enable Audit Failure logs in Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/391734/how-to-enable-audit-failure-logs-in-active-directory).

Answer (score 2):

Check credential manager for anything that may have your AD password stored, this can be in the form of a Windows Credential.

Often times Outlook can cause this by keeping your password cached and then trying to start with the incorrect password.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Search for credential manager from the start screen.  When it opens, it will list the stored credentials it knows about.

Comment: What applications are installed?  Have you restarted after you changed your password?

Comment: Yes, several times.